# EclipseLink - JPA and MOXy - different views on the same data model

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, moxy

here is the challange...

I have a complex distributed system based on the same model

It looks like this:

```
A <-(XML)-> B <-(JSON)-> C
```

A, B and C are different Applications basicaly **based on the same model**, so I decided to maintain the model in a seperate Java (Maven) Project.

- Each application uses JPA for persistance
- Each application uses and persists **only a subset of the entities attributes**
- The data exchange format ist based on the same model (XML or JSON with MOXy)
- There are two exchange formats which uses **only a subset of the entities attributes**

Here is a more technical example of an entity (pseudocode):

```
class Foo {
  a;
  ab;
  bc;
  c;
  ac;
  // ...
}
```

where a is used by the Application A, ab is used by the Application A and the Application B, bc is used by the Application B and C, etc...

The same requirement for the exchange format.

Do you have any idea how to implement it?

Best regards.

Edit:
The probably best solution for that problem is to autogenerate different classes out of a global model. Taken the Entity from the example above, this would looks like this:

Application A:

```
class Foo {
  a;
  ab;
  ac;
  // ...
}
```

Application B:

```
class Foo {
  ab;
  bc;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EclipseLink 2.5.0 you can leverage MOXy's `@XmlNamedObjectGraphs` extension for this use case.  An EclipseLink 2.5.0 release candidate can be downloaded from the following link:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/milestones.php

**Domain Model (Foo)**

The `@XmlNamedObjectGraph` extension allows you to specify subsets of your mappings that can be used with marshalling and unmarshalling.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@XmlNamedObjectGraphs({ 
    @XmlNamedObjectGraph(
        name="a",
        attributeNodes={
            @XmlNamedAttributeNode("a"),
            @XmlNamedAttributeNode("ab"),
            @XmlNamedAttributeNode("ac")
        }
    ),
    @XmlNamedObjectGraph(
        name="b",
        attributeNodes={
            @XmlNamedAttributeNode("ab"),
            @XmlNamedAttributeNode("bc")
        }
    ),
    @XmlNamedObjectGraph(
        name="c",
        attributeNodes={
            @XmlNamedAttributeNode("bc"),
            @XmlNamedAttributeNode("c"),
            @XmlNamedAttributeNode("ac")
        }
    )

})
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    int a;
    int ab;
    int bc;
    int c;
    int ac;

}
```

**Demo**

In the demo code below we will populate one instance of `Foo` and then output it four different ways leveraging the object graphs that we defined.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.a = 1;
        foo.ab = 2;
        foo.ac = 3;
        foo.bc = 4;
        foo.c = 5;

        // Marshal to XML - Everything
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);

        // Marshal to XML - Application A
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, "a");
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);

        // Marshal to JSON - Application B
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, "b");
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);

        // Marshal to JSON - Application C
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, "c");
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below are the four different views that we produced from our demo code.  Remember we marshalled the exact same instance of `Foo` each time with the same data populated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <a>1</a>
   <ab>2</ab>
   <bc>4</bc>
   <c>5</c>
   <ac>3</ac>
</foo>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <a>1</a>
   <ab>2</ab>
   <ac>3</ac>
</foo>
{
   "foo" : {
      "ab" : 2,
      "bc" : 4
   }
}{
   "foo" : {
      "bc" : 4,
      "c" : 5,
      "ac" : 3
   }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-inputoutput-partial.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Hi Blaise Doughan, thank you... that's an extension I'm looking for. It's very usefull, when you have to write the client side (webapp, Android, ...) anyway. But when you like to keep Java and MOXy on the clientside (you gave examples for marshalling but not for unmarshalling) it would be nice to autogenerate the clients entity classes out of the annotations. Otherwise you have some "null" properties... the model is inconsistent. In my opinion the only one solution is to autogenerate code for the client (on the unmarshalling side). Any chance to get this feature in the next release?

Comment: What about the JPA stuff? In my opinion the JAXB spec (in this case this is "just" an EclipseLink extension, but anyway) should work together with the JPA spec. What do you think?

Comment: @kalamar - Unmarshalling works the same way, you just set the property on the `Unmarshaller` instead of the `Marshaller`.  I could see us adding a feature where you could generate a schema based on the object graph and then generating a model from that.  JPA 2.1 has named entity graphs that work almost identically to MOXy's named object graphs.  Everything we put in EclipseLink MOXy is designed to be compatible with JPA, as EclipseLink is also a JPA provider.

Answer (score 1):

If the models are very different, than perhaps just have different models, or possibly use inheritance.

For JPA you can define the mappings in an orm.xml and choose to map what you wish, so you can use the same model, just have a different orm.xml for each application.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have already considered that. The problem here is, that when `A -(marshall)-(XML)-(unmarshall)-> B` you still have to use the **full** model in Application B. I mean, you still have the same Object classes in Application B. That would mean, you have some unused properties or relations. I think the only one solution for that is to generate custom code (*.java files) out of a global model based on some self written @ViewModel annotations (work in progress). Thx anyway.